# Python 3.x Socket programming not working for jpg files

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am new to python, and try to learn socket programming. My intention is to make a GET request to get a JPG file and then save it locally on a disk. The version of python is 3.6, and I am not sure how to decode it. The code removes the header and then saves only the header:

Here is the code:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(("www.py4inf.com",80))
mysock.send(b"GET http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg HTTP/1.0\n\n")
count = 0
pic = ""

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(5120)
    print(type(data))
    count = count + len(data)
    print("The count is:" , count, "\n")
    print("The len of data is: ",len(data), "\n")
    pic = pic + data
mysock.close()

pos = pic.find("\r\n\r\n")
print('Header length',pos)
print(pic[:pos])

# Skip past the header and save the picture data

picture = pic[pos+4:]
print(pic)
fhand = open("stuff.jpg","wb")
fhand.write(pic)
fhand.close()
```

This would work in python 2.x but not in python 3.x, can someone please advise on this. I tried searching a lot, but wasn't able to find much, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the error:
Here is the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chap12socket.py", line 37, in <module>
    pic = pic + data
TypeError: must be str, not bytes

Comment: Try: `pic = b""`. That will get you over the current error (most likely there are others as well).